# java jradiobutton or jcheckbox for text

Tags: java, string, swing, jcheckbox, jradiobutton

i am trying to make a desktop app that would display a line of text based on the selected radio buttons, but so far all i can get is a single part of the lane based on the most recent selected JRadioButton.

Ideally i would want the end output to be based on which buttons were selected, instead of just a single output based on the last button selected.

Would it be better to change to JCheckBox and then it would generate the text afterwards based on lines selected?

Edit: right now if hvba and hfba are selected, the text only appears for the last button selected and not for both, so i was wondering how to get both of them to show up. Added an edit.

```
public class Gui extends JFrame{
private JTextArea ta;
private JRadioButton hvba, hvbr, hfba, hfbr, cab;
private ButtonGroup group1, group2;
private String hva, hvr, hfa, hfr, ca;

public Gui(){
    super("QA Narrative tool");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    ta = new JTextArea("QA Narrative", 5, 25);
    add(ta);

    hvba = new JRadioButton("Add HV", false);
    hvbr = new JRadioButton("Remove HV", false);
    hfba = new JRadioButton("Add HF", false);
    hfbr = new JRadioButton("Remove HF", false);
    cab = new JRadioButton("Clear all", true);
    add(hvba);
    add(hvbr);
    add(hfba);
    add(hfbr);
    add(cab);

    group1 = new ButtonGroup();
    group1.add(hvba);
    group1.add(hvbr);
    group1.add(cab);

    group2 = new ButtonGroup();
    group2.add(hfba);
    group2.add(hfbr);
    group2.add(cab);

    hva = new String("add HV reason code");
    hvr = new String("remove HV reason code");
    hfa = new String("add HF reason code");
    hfr = new String("remove HF reason code");
    ca = new String("");

    hvba.addItemListener(new HandlerClass(hva));
    hvbr.addItemListener(new HandlerClass(hvr));
    hfba.addItemListener(new HandlerClass(hfa));
    hfbr.addItemListener(new HandlerClass(hfr));
    cab.addItemListener(new HandlerClass(ca));
}

private class HandlerClass implements ItemListener{
    private String string;

    public HandlerClass(String s){
        string = s;
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
        ta.setText("Please " + string + " .");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Wait, what's wrong with the code you've posted?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels nothing seems to be broken, OP needs opinions about what is better between CheckBoxes or RadioButtons....

Comment: ? There's no intrinsic difference other than that they're commonly used for different purposes. You a checkbox if you're not going to link them in a ButtonGroup and a JRadioButton if you are.

Comment: I was not clear, right now if hvba and hfba are selected, the text only appears for the last button selected and not for both, so i was wondering how to get both of them to show up. Added an edit.

Comment: Let the buttons share a common `HandlerClass` that can inspect the state of both groups.

Comment: @trashgod how would i go about doing that? could you give an example as i dont really understand.

Comment: You can get needed information from the `ItemEvent`; some examples maybe found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjava%5d%20ItemListener); then, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach..